# classList is only affect the first li in the ul despect the fact that all the elements where selected

Tags: scroll, nav, wp-nav-menu-item

classList is only affect the first li in the ul despect the fact that all the elements where selected.

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const headerChangejh = document.querySelector(".nav-link");
  if (window.scrollY > 0) {
    headerChangejh.classList.add("scrolledy");
  } else {
    headerChangejh.classList.remove("scrolledy");
  }
})
```

```css
  .nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: 0.7s ease;
  color: black;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
  .nav-link.scrolledy {
    color: #2196f3;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">For Individual</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">For Companies</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">App</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Jobs</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

the above code only changes the first li in the ul, while other remain unchange despite the fact that all the elements was selected

Comment: `querySelector` is not the same thing as `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Also, your CSS is invalid: you cannot nest CSS rules ([though this will be enabled soon](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/css-nesting/))

Comment: i have tried the querySelectorAll but it not working too. in fact when used, none of li color will change when scrolled

Comment: Please, any other help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm unsure what effect you're after, as the current `'scroll'` event-listener simply colors all `.nav-link` elements based on whether or not the window has scrolled - instead of coloring elements based on, say, how far down the page they are or how much the user scrolled-passed, around, or over them. Your question-post does not describe the ultimate effect you're after, so I largely left it as-is.
- As for bugs-in-your-code:

  - You need to use `querySelectorAll`, not `querySelector`, to get *all* matching elements - using `querySelector` will return only the *first* matching element (i.e. your "For Individual" `<li>`)

    - Also, even if your code used `querySelectorAll`, your `scroll` event-listener does not iterate over all matched elements: it just has a single `if` to add/remove a CSS class-name. I've replaced it with a `for(of)` loop (which is better than using `.forEach` because there's no implicit closure) that uses the `toggle( className, force )` method, for more succinct code.
  - Your CSS was malformed: you needed to fix it, as below:

    **Malformed CSS**:

    ```
    .nav-link:hover {
      color: red;
     .nav-link.scrolledy {
      color: #2196f3;
    }
    ```

    **Fixed CSS**:

    ```
    .nav-link:hover {
      color: red;
    }
    .nav-link.scrolledy {
      color: #2196f3;
    }
    ```
- Additionally, I made the `.nav-link` elements bigger so you can better see the `transition:`  to their `color` property.

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
  for (const l of links) l.classList.toggle('scrolledy', window.scrollY > 0);
})
```

```css
.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: color 0.7s ease;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.nav-link:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: red;
}

.nav-link.scrolledy {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">For Individual</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">For Companies</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">App</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Jobs</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: that fix it. The CSS was a typo error. fully understood while the if only changes the color of one of the elements in the array instead of all.   the for(of) loop changes all. thanks